# Updating a multi-select lookup column REST

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, sharepoint-2010, single-page-application

***Short Version:***
I need help or an example of updating a multi-select lookup column REST. I have been unable to add or update the multi-select lookup column.

---

details

**What I am trying to do:** 
  Update a list item with updated multiple lookup IDs from a SPA. I would like to understand what I should look for and how to apply it. And i assume that Adding a row would be of the same ilk.

**My imposed limitations:** This has to be done with client side code. I cannot deploy a wsp/binary code. :( SP2010 I am stuck in the dark ages with jQuery 1.8.3 and the site rendering in document mode IE=8 running on IE11.

**What works:**
All CRUDs not involving multi look ups. Reads with multi look ups is working in a separate call using the *...ListName(ID)/MultiLookupCol* shape.

**What I have tried or researched:**
I believe the closest I have gotten is this. However it is still a fail with the **Bad Request Error : Error processing request stream. The payload must represent a valid array format for collections.**

So I believe that my properties construction for the multi is as unstable as Charles Manson. Assuming that's my culprit, I don't know how to fix it.

Using

```
var itemProperties = {
    "__metadata": { "type": 'Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.GroupsOfNumbersItem' },
```

stopped the *type name error* I was getting. Closer but still not there.

```
var aIDs = [1, 3];
var itemProperties = {
    "__metadata": { "type": 'Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.MyNumbersItem' },
    "ReferenceLookup": { "results": aIDs }
};
updateListItem(myWebUrl(), 
               "GroupsOfNumbers", 
               1, 
               itemProperties,
    function () {
        console.log('Success');
    },
    function (error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
);
```

I have read and tried to apply info from a multitude of pages the most pertinent seem to be the following.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84560/updating-lookup-values-with-the-rest-api

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/69983/updating-a-multiselect-field-via-rest-api-2010

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115950/sharepoint-2013-rest-api-to-update-list-item-uncaught-referenceerror-etag-is-n

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/uksharepoint/2013/02/22/manipulating-list-items-in-sharepoint-hosted-apps-using-the-rest-api/

I have included results for the following calls from the browser window in hopes it helps.

Results from joedev/mftt/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/GroupsOfNumbers

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xml:base="http://joedev/mftt/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">GroupsOfNumbers</title>
  <id>http://joedev/mftt/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/GroupsOfNumbers/</id>
  <updated>2016-07-09T02:00:17Z</updated>
  <link rel="self" title="GroupsOfNumbers" href="GroupsOfNumbers" />
  <entry m:etag="W/&quot;1&quot;">
    <id>http://joedev/mftt/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/GroupsOfNumbers(1)</id>
    <title type="text">My First Test</title>
    <updated>2016-07-08T21:01:04-04:00</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="GroupsOfNumbersItem" href="GroupsOfNumbers(1)" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/NumberLookUp" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="NumberLookUp" href="GroupsOfNumbers(1)/NumberLookUp" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/CreatedBy" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="CreatedBy" href="GroupsOfNumbers(1)/CreatedBy" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ModifiedBy" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="ModifiedBy" href="GroupsOfNumbers(1)/ModifiedBy" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Attachments" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Attachments" href="GroupsOfNumbers(1)/Attachments" />
    <category term="Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.GroupsOfNumbersItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:ContentTypeID>0x0100F35C84ED82881449AC47D1675F099E2C</d:ContentTypeID>
        <d:Title>My First Test</d:Title>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:Id>
        <d:ContentType>Item</d:ContentType>
        <d:Modified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-07-08T21:01:04</d:Modified>
        <d:Created m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-07-08T21:01:04</d:Created>
        <d:CreatedById m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:CreatedById>
        <d:ModifiedById m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:ModifiedById>
        <d:Owshiddenversion m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:Owshiddenversion>
        <d:Version>1.0</d:Version>
        <d:Path>/mftt/Lists/GroupsOfNumbers</d:Path>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

Results from joedev/mftt/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/GroupsOfNumbers(1)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<entry xml:base="http://joedev/mftt/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:etag="W/&quot;1&quot;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <id>http://joedev/mftt/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/GroupsOfNumbers(1)</id>
  <title type="text">My First Test</title>
  <updated>2016-07-08T21:01:04-04:00</updated>
  <author>
    <name />
  </author>
  <link rel="edit" title="GroupsOfNumbersItem" href="GroupsOfNumbers(1)" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/NumberLookUp" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="NumberLookUp" href="GroupsOfNumbers(1)/NumberLookUp" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/CreatedBy" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="CreatedBy" href="GroupsOfNumbers(1)/CreatedBy" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ModifiedBy" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="ModifiedBy" href="GroupsOfNumbers(1)/ModifiedBy" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Attachments" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Attachments" href="GroupsOfNumbers(1)/Attachments" />
  <category term="Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.GroupsOfNumbersItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
  <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
      <d:ContentTypeID>0x0100F35C84ED82881449AC47D1675F099E2C</d:ContentTypeID>
      <d:Title>My First Test</d:Title>
      <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:Id>
      <d:ContentType>Item</d:ContentType>
      <d:Modified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-07-08T21:01:04</d:Modified>
      <d:Created m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-07-08T21:01:04</d:Created>
      <d:CreatedById m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:CreatedById>
      <d:ModifiedById m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:ModifiedById>
      <d:Owshiddenversion m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:Owshiddenversion>
      <d:Version>1.0</d:Version>
      <d:Path>/mftt/Lists/GroupsOfNumbers</d:Path>
    </m:properties>
  </content>
</entry>
```

Results from joedev/mftt/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/GroupsOfNumbers(1)/NumberLookUp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xml:base="http://joedev/mftt/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">NumberLookUp</title>
  <id>http://joedev/mftt/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/GroupsOfNumbers(1)/NumberLookUp/</id>
  <updated>2016-07-09T02:00:10Z</updated>
  <link rel="self" title="NumberLookUp" href="NumberLookUp" />
  <entry m:etag="W/&quot;1&quot;">
    <id>http://joedev/mftt/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MyNumbers(4)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2016-07-08T20:55:47-04:00</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="MyNumbersItem" href="MyNumbers(4)" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/CreatedBy" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="CreatedBy" href="MyNumbers(4)/CreatedBy" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ModifiedBy" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="ModifiedBy" href="MyNumbers(4)/ModifiedBy" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Attachments" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Attachments" href="MyNumbers(4)/Attachments" />
    <category term="Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.MyNumbersItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:ContentTypeID>0x0100913060DC06F4DF458B6A06CA950C1149</d:ContentTypeID>
        <d:Title m:null="true" />
        <d:NunberName>Five</d:NunberName>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">4</d:Id>
        <d:ContentType>Item</d:ContentType>
        <d:Modified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-07-08T20:55:47</d:Modified>
        <d:Created m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-07-08T20:55:47</d:Created>
        <d:CreatedById m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:CreatedById>
        <d:ModifiedById m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:ModifiedById>
        <d:Owshiddenversion m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:Owshiddenversion>
        <d:Version>1.0</d:Version>
        <d:Path>/mftt/Lists/MyNumbers</d:Path>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry m:etag="W/&quot;1&quot;">
    <id>http://joedev/mftt/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MyNumbers(5)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2016-07-08T20:55:54-04:00</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="MyNumbersItem" href="MyNumbers(5)" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/CreatedBy" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="CreatedBy" href="MyNumbers(5)/CreatedBy" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ModifiedBy" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="ModifiedBy" href="MyNumbers(5)/ModifiedBy" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Attachments" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Attachments" href="MyNumbers(5)/Attachments" />
    <category term="Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.MyNumbersItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:ContentTypeID>0x0100913060DC06F4DF458B6A06CA950C1149</d:ContentTypeID>
        <d:Title m:null="true" />
        <d:NunberName>Four</d:NunberName>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">5</d:Id>
        <d:ContentType>Item</d:ContentType>
        <d:Modified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-07-08T20:55:54</d:Modified>
        <d:Created m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-07-08T20:55:54</d:Created>
        <d:CreatedById m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:CreatedById>
        <d:ModifiedById m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:ModifiedById>
        <d:Owshiddenversion m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:Owshiddenversion>
        <d:Version>1.0</d:Version>
        <d:Path>/mftt/Lists/MyNumbers</d:Path>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry m:etag="W/&quot;1&quot;">
    <id>http://joedev/mftt/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MyNumbers(6)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2016-07-08T20:56:13-04:00</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="MyNumbersItem" href="MyNumbers(6)" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/CreatedBy" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="CreatedBy" href="MyNumbers(6)/CreatedBy" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ModifiedBy" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="ModifiedBy" href="MyNumbers(6)/ModifiedBy" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Attachments" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Attachments" href="MyNumbers(6)/Attachments" />
    <category term="Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.MyNumbersItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:ContentTypeID>0x0100913060DC06F4DF458B6A06CA950C1149</d:ContentTypeID>
        <d:Title m:null="true" />
        <d:NunberName>One</d:NunberName>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">6</d:Id>
        <d:ContentType>Item</d:ContentType>
        <d:Modified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-07-08T20:56:13</d:Modified>
        <d:Created m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-07-08T20:56:13</d:Created>
        <d:CreatedById m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:CreatedById>
        <d:ModifiedById m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:ModifiedById>
        <d:Owshiddenversion m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:Owshiddenversion>
        <d:Version>1.0</d:Version>
        <d:Path>/mftt/Lists/MyNumbers</d:Path>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

here are my update functions for completeness.

```
function getListItemById(webUrl, listName, itemId, success, failure) {
    var url = webUrl + "/_vti_bin/Listdata.svc/" + listName + "(" + itemId + ") ";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data.d);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            if (debug == true) {
                console.log("getListItemById ID:" + itemId);
                if (data.responseJSON) {
                    console.dir("Data: " + data);
                }
            }
            if (data.responseJSON) {
                failure(data.responseJSON.error);
            } else {
                console.log("getListItemById No data returned for ID: " + itemId);
            }

        }
    });
}

function updateListItem(webUrl, listName, itemId, itemProperties, success, failure) {
    getListItemById(webUrl, listName, itemId, function (item) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: item.__metadata.uri,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            processData: false,
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
                "If-Match": item.__metadata.etag
            },
            data: Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize(itemProperties),
            success: function (data) {
                success(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                failure(data);
            }
        });

    },
    function (error) {
        failure(error);
    });

}
```

Comment: I tested Thriggle's answer and it works for me. I noticed in ItemProperties you have "ReferenceLookup" but the rest of your code looks like the column name is "NumberLookup". Also, when I tested it it did NOT work when the lookup column was referencing a document set, although I believe REST is broken when operating on document sets in SP 2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Adding selections to a multivalue lookup field using REST**

Here's the necessary format for your data payload:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
    MultiLookupColumnName:[
        { 
            __metadata: { 
                uri: "http://yoursiteurl/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/LookupListName(1)"
            }
        },
         { 
            __metadata: { 
                uri: "http://yoursiteurl/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/LookupListName(2)"
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

This example assumes that your lookup column is named `MultiLookupColumnName`, that the list that your lookup column is looking up against is entitled `LookupListName`, and that you want to set your multi-lookup field to lookup to the items with IDs 1 and 2.

In your code, you would use that `data` variable in place of your `itemProperties` variable.

For the sake of completeness, here's a full example without jQuery:

```
var idOfItemToUpdate = 1;
var url = "/serverRelativeUrl/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/YourListName("+idOfItemToUpdate+")"
var data = JSON.stringify({
    MultiLookupColumnName:[
        {__metadata:{uri:"http://yoursiteurl/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/LookupListName(1)"}},
        {__metadata:{uri:"http://yoursiteurl/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/LookupListName(2)"}}
    ]
});
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST",url,true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-HTTP-Method", "MERGE");
xhr.setRequestHeader("If-Match", "*");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
xhr.send(data);
```

**Removing selections from a multivalue lookup field using REST**

Note that to remove a value from the multi-selection lookup field, you'll need to use a different operation. The above operation only adds to the selected values.

To remove a selected value from the field, use a `DELETE` operation like so:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("DELETE",
    "/serverRelativeUrl/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/YourListName(1)/$links/MultiLookupColumnName(2)",
    true);
xhr.send();
```

That code would remove the lookup value with an item ID of 2 from the field named `MultiLookupColumnName` on the item with an ID of 1 on the list named `YourListName`.

(Can you diagram that sentence?)

**Footnote: Callback functions without jQuery**

I used `XMLHttpRequest` for the above examples, but I don't want that to cause you any headaches down the road.

If you decide to use the built-in `XMLHttpRequest` instead of a jQuery/AJAX wrapper, you can use its `onreadystatechange` event and pass it a callback function like so:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4){
        myCallbackFunction(xhr.status, xhr.responseText);
    }
};

function myCallbackFunction(status, text){
    // decide what to do based on the status
}
```

Comment: This works swimmingly.  Is there a way to delete all the "MultiLookupColumnName" entries from "YourListName" ?  I am using a MERGE so new items are added to the existing ones.

Comment: Not that I know of; I don't think you can delete multiple values from the field in a single request, and I think you need to know which exact values you want to remove. One way would be to first GET the field value, then iterate through those results and perform a DELETE for each selected value in the field. ...That does seem unnecessarily complicated, though, doesn't it?

Comment: System says I have to wait 9 more hours to award the bounty.  But I will once it lets me.

Comment: what would be the jQuery/AJAX wrapper method to delete the lookups?

Comment: Regarding the deleting all. I did try to tunnel the PUT verb rather than the MERGE verb and SP responded with an error about using PUTs with multi lookups.

Comment: I believe the jQuery AJAX wrapper for deleting would just be `$.ajax({url:"/serverRelativeUrl/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/YourListName(1)/$links/MultiLookupColumnName(2)",type:"DELETE"});`